# The coefficient of concordance for vague data

Tags: r, algorithm, math, correlation, ranking

I'm trying to adapt a formula that calculates the coefficient of concordance for vague data. The paper that describes it is here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4738093_The_coefficient_of_concordance_for_vague_data

The specific equation I'm interested in is (22)

[image: coefficient of concordance for vague data]

There are four observers (i.e.k=4) and eight objects (i.e.n=8). The answer should be 0.7485

I can work out the equation in R for the standard equation of Kendall's W but not this one. I think I'm just messing up the order of operations.

In R I think input values should be:

```
u <- c(6/7, 4/7, 1, 1/7, 2/7, 3/7, 5/7, 0,
5/7, 4/7, 6/7, 1/7, 2/7, 3/7, 0, 0,
    1, 5/7, 2/7, 0, 2/7, 4/7, 6/7, 1/7,
        5/7, 3/7, 4/7, 0, 2/7, 0, 6/7, 1/7)
v<-c(1/7, 3/7, 0, 6/7, 5/7, 4/7, 2/7, 1,
1/7, 2/7, 0, 5/7, 4/7, 3/7, 0, 6/7,
    0, 2/7, 4/7, 1, 4/7, 3/7, 1/7, 6/7,
        1/7, 3/7, 2/7, 6/7, 4/7, 0, 0, 5/7)
```

You can see these values at the bottom of page 320 and top of page 321

Hope you can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vectors are correct and values of k = 4 and n = 8 are correct as well. This means there is an error in Kendall's coefficient of concordance computation. It is impossible to help you further without the code being shown other than [here](https://github.com/spinlockirqsave/math) I put the spreadsheet kendall_concordance.ods that performs this computation so hopefully it'll do the job for you. I got 0.7485 result as expected.

What you should do is:

```
1. Build u, v vectors (you have done this)

2. Calculate averages of each column in u and v (2n averages).

3. Subtract 0.5 from all averages and square them (for all av in u:
   av = (av - 1/2)^2, same for v) so they are now distances from
   ideal concordance for each column

4. Sum all 16 distances and multiply by 6(n-1)/(n(n+1))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'll build up a working R function and add it as an answer.

Comment: I'm being blind to it but where in the equation does it specify to do point 2, calculate column averages?

Comment: @ManassaMauler In your equation (which corresponds to eq 22 in document) u_a(x_j) and v_a(x_j) are the averages of values of membership and nonmembership functions u and v (mi and v in document,  equations 14 and 15)

Answer (score 0):

I've built the function for the formula in R as follows:

```
vagueKendall<-function(u,v,n){
  u<-matrix (u, ncol=n, byrow = TRUE)
  v<-matrix (v, ncol=n, byrow = TRUE)
    ## divide by n-1 
  uColNo<-u/(n-1)
  vColNo<-v/(n-1)
    ## take the averages
  colMeansU<-colMeans(uColNo)
  colMeansV<-colMeans(vColNo)
    ## measure the distances from the averages 
  au = (colMeansU - 1/2)^2
  av = (colMeansV - 1/2)^2
    ## calculate component before sum
  outside<-6*(n-1)/(n*(n+1))
    ## sum of squared distances from averages 
  sumSqdDiff<-sum(au+av)
    ## The product of these gives the modified Kendall's W
  W<-outside*sum(au+av)
  return(W)
}
```

The second function will calculate the p-value for this (I hope):

```
## Extract p-value function
vagueKendallP<-function(W,k,n){
## Calculate correlation coefficient 
r<-(k*W-1)/(k-1)
## Calculate Chi Squared
Chi<-k*(n-1)*W
## degrees of freedom
df<-n-1
## p-value 
pValue<-pchisq(Chi,df, lower.tail = FALSE)
return(pValue)
}
```